# Solving $x^k+y^k+z^k=w^k$ non-trivially in strictly positive integers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $x^k+y^k+z^k=w^k$ in $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$.

If we look for solutions that are strictly positive and non-trivial i.e. $x\neq-y$, $x\neq w$ etc... then using Mathematica it's easy to find solutions for $2\leq k\leq4$ but not for $k\geq5$:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\{k=2:\{x\to 6,y\to 3,z\to 2,w\to 7\}\},\\ &\{k=3:\{x\to 6,y\to 8,z\to 1,w\to 9\}\},\\ &\{k=4:\{x\to 18796760,y\to 2682440,z\to 15365639,w\to 20615673\}\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

For $k=2$ we also have an infinite number of non-trivial solutions - see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/950347/157467) for a complete parametrisation.

This raises the questions:

> For $k=3,4$ does the equation have an infinite number of strictly positive non-trivial solutions?

> For $k\geq5$ can it be proved that there are no strictly positive non-trivial solutions?

Analogous to the case for FLT, that the 4-variable ABC conjecture could show that we have only finitely many non-trivial solutions for $k$ large enough but I haven't worked this out in detail.

**Update:** After Alexander Kalmynin's comment it occurred to me that $k=3$ and $k=4$ could have parametrisations. On searching I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/470114/157467) for $k=3$ giving a general parametric solution and as noted by Daniel Loughran [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413031/how-many-cubes-are-the-sum-of-three-positive-cubes/413176?noredirect=1#comment1059058_413176). We also have Noam Elkies' paper ["On A^4+B^4+C^4=D^4"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2008781) for $k=4$ which gives an infinite sequence of solutions but no parametrisation. Note that this was a significant result as it disproved the case n=4 of [Euler's conjectured generalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) of Fermat's Last Theorem.

In fact for $k=4$ there is no parametrisation - see Daniel Loughran's comments below.

Comment: For the first question, $k=3$, choose a positive rational $b=p/q<1/\sqrt[3]{9}$, use the identity $(9b^4)^3+(3b-9b^4)^3+(1-9b^3)^3=1$ and multiply it by $q^{12}$. So yes, we have infinitely many primitive non-trivial positive solutions

Comment: @AlexanderKalmynin Thanks Alexander that is really elegant! Your comment made me think there might be general parametrisations for k=3 and4 which was confirmed on searching. I have added the relevant information to my question.

Comment: Famous conjecture of Lander, Parkin, and Selfridge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture implies that there are no non-trivial solutions for $k \geq 5$. They made very extensive computer search and found no solutions. On the other hand, if there are no solutions, then the proof is expected to be difficult.

Comment: See also http://euler.free.fr for various numerical results on equations with sums of like powers.

Comment: I think it should be Elkies' or Elkies's

Comment: For $k =3$ see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413031/how-many-cubes-are-the-sum-of-three-positive-cubes/413176?noredirect=1#comment1059058_413176

Comment: For $k =4$ there is no parametrisation since this is a K3 surface hence a non-rational variety. It does however contain lots of elliptic curves.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk Thanks that is very useful information!

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Likewise thank you Max!

Comment: @DanielLoughran Appreciate your comments Daniel I have added some extra information to my question based on them.